# Creating Large Random Content Files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, solid-state-drive

I am working on characterizing an SSD drive to determine max TBW / life expectancy.

Currently I am using BASH to generate 500MB files with random (non-zero) content :

```
dd if=<(openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero) of=/media/m2_adv3d/abc${stamp1} bs=1MB count=500 iflag=fullblock&

Note : {stamp1} is a time stamp for ensuring unique file names.
```

I am looking to accomplish the same result in Python but am not finding efficient ways to do this (generate the file quickly).

Looking for suggestions.

Thanks!

---

Update

I have been experimenting with the following and seem to have achieved 2 second write; files appear to be random and different :

```
import os

newfile = open("testfile.001", "a")
newfile.write (os.urandom(500000000))    # generate 500MB random content file
newfile.close ()
```

A little skeptical that this is truly good enough to stress an SSD.  Basically going to infinitely loop this; once drive is full, deleting to oldest file and writing new one, and collecting SMART data every 500 files written to trend the aging.

Thoughts?

Thanks,

Dan.

Comment: Perhaps if you edited the question to show the code you would like speeded up people will suggest improvements. Hard to answer without seeing the existing code.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @holdenweb; updated with code.

Comment: One thought: since the IO operation is bound to take time, a threaded or asynchronous solution that allows a new random block to be generated while the last one is being written might speed things up.

Comment: @holdenweb ; thank you for the suggestions.  Tried threading and took a performance hit ... while I seem to be able to consistently write 500MB files at 3 ~ 5 seconds a piece (linear); when I attempt to do two in parallel using threads, I am hitting between 10 ~ 17 seconds ... more towards the 17 seconds.  Will post the code for reference and close this one off.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The os.urandom option works best for generating large random files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something as easy as this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rows = 100000
cols = 10000

table_size = [rows,cols]

x = np.ones(table_size)
pd.DataFrame(x).to_csv(path)
```

You can update the table size to make it larger or smaller. I am not sure if this is more / less efficient than what you are already trying.

Comment: Trying different approach (see edited question above).